# In Excel, I need to display the content of a cell if 2 other conditions are met

Tags: excel-formula

In Excel, I want BL5 to display nothing only if BA5 is a "0". However, IF H5 is EQUAL to "1" AND BA5 is "y", THEN I want BL5 to display the content of A5.

Is there any possible way of doing this? Thank you all in advance

Comment: `=if(BA5=0, "", IF(AND(H5=1, BA5="y"), A5, ""))` Which reads "IF BA5 is 0 then nothing, else if H5 is 1 AND BA5 is "y" then A5 else nothing"

Answer (score 1):

In BL5,

```
=IF(AND(NOT(BA5=0), AND(H5=1, BA5="Y")), A5, "")
```

If the contents of BA5 are not 0, and H5=1 and BA5="Y", then display the contents of A5, otherwise display an empty string (nothing). This also displays nothing in the event that H5 does not equal 1 or BA5 does not equal "Y".

Strictly speaking it only displays the contents of A5 in the event that BA5 is not 0, H5 is 1, and BA5 is "Y".

I think that meets your requirements, but it's not perfectly clear from your post.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response.

I may not have been the clearest in my question, I apologize.

I want BL5 to populate the value in A5 IF H5 EQUALS "1" AND BA 5 EQUALS "y".